# Rename specific query parameter during redirect in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want redirect urls like `/catalogsearch/result/?q=[keyword]` to `/products?keyword=[keyword]`. Whats wrong with following rule?

```
location ~ /catalogsearch/result/?q=(.*) {
    rewrite ^ /products?keyword=$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` and anything after it (the *query string*) is not part of the *normalized URI* used by the `location` and `rewrite` directives.

Assuming that there is only one parameter, you can access it using the [`$arg_` family of variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_).

```
location = /catalogsearch/result/ {
    return 301 /products?keyword=$arg_q;
}
```